# Split timestamp column into separate date and time columns in excel

Tags: excel, timestamp

I have a dataframe with a thousand timestamps like the following one:

`05.03.2018 08:18:37.827`

I am having difficulties splitting this timestamp into two columns: Date and Time. I am not able to use the formula `=INT(A2) and then =A2-B2` because the date is like this `05.03.2018`. It should have been this `05/03/2018`.

However, it is impossible for me to change the `.` to `/` for all the cells. It will take days to do it.
If someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Date:
`=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/",1),".","/",1))`

Time:
`=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/",1),".","/",1))`

[image]